# Exporting GridView to Excel without gridview cells with hyperlinks showing red

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have an ASP.Net 4.0 GridView and a button which exports the GridView data to Excel. This all works fine. However, within the GridView, the text in three cells of each row are red because they are hyperlinks. When I export the data to Excel, these cells are still red. I want them to be black. How do I do this?  Here's my code:

```
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Mobile.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/excel";

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

        foreach (GridViewRow gridViewRow in gvResults.Rows)
        {
            gridViewRow.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            foreach (TableCell gridViewRowTableCell in gridViewRow.Cells)
                gridViewRowTableCell.Style["forecolor"] = "#000000";
            if (gridViewRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < gridViewRow.Cells.Count; columnIndex++)
                {
                    gridViewRow.Cells[columnIndex].Attributes.Add("class", "text");
                }

            }
        }

        gvResults.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
        string style = @"<style> .text { mso-number-format:\@; } </style> ";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
        Response.End();
```

And here's the code for the links. This runs OnDataBound:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvResults.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || row.RowType == DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow)
            {
                string imei = row.Cells[0].Text;
                if (imei != "&nbsp;")
                {
                    string imeiLink = "window.location='SmartphoneInventory.aspx?imei=" + imei + "';";
                    row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("onClick", String.Format(imeiLink));
                    row.Cells[0].Text = "<span style='color:red'>" + row.Cells[0].Text + "</span>";
                }

                string phonenumber = row.Cells[1].Text;
                if (phonenumber != "&nbsp;")
                {
                    string phonenumberLink = "window.location='SmartphoneInventory.aspx?phonenumber=" + phonenumber + "';";
                    row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("onClick", String.Format(phonenumberLink));
                    row.Cells[1].Text = "<span style='color:red'>" + row.Cells[1].Text + "</span>";
                }

                int cellCount = row.Cells.Count;
                string empName = row.Cells[cellCount - 1].Text;
                if (empName != "&nbsp;")
                {
                    string empNameLink = "window.location='DevicesByEmployee.aspx?empName=" + empName + "';";
                    row.Cells[cellCount - 1].Attributes.Add("onClick", String.Format(empNameLink));
                    row.Cells[cellCount - 1].Text = "<span style='color:red'>" + row.Cells[cellCount - 1].Text + "</span>";
                }
            }
        }
```

I guess what I need is how to re-style the span. Is this possible? The GridView autogenerates its columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the LinkButton Text, assign it to the GridView Cell Text and Remove control.

Here is ho I do it in the header:

**C#**

```
foreach (TableCell c in gv.HeaderRow.Cells) {
    if (c.HasControls) {
        c.Text = (c.Controls(0) as LinkButton).Text;
        c.Controls.Clear();
    }
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
For Each c As TableCell In gv.HeaderRow.Cells
    If c.HasControls Then
        c.Text = TryCast(c.Controls(0), LinkButton).Text
        c.Controls.Clear()
    End If
Next
```

EDIT:

Create an extension method:

**C#**

```
[Extension()]
public string StripTags(string html)
{
    return Regex.Replace(html, "<.*?>", "");
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
<Extension> _
Public Function StripTags(html As String) As String
    Return Regex.Replace(html, "<.*?>", "")
End Function
```

It will remove tags from your string, therefore your style. Use as follows:

```
    foreach (GridViewRow gridViewRow in gvResults.Rows)
    {
        gridViewRow.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        foreach (TableCell gridViewRowTableCell in gridViewRow.Cells)
            gridViewRowTableCell.Style["forecolor"] = "#000000";
        if (gridViewRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < gridViewRow.Cells.Count; columnIndex++)
            {
                gridViewRow.Cells[columnIndex].Text = gridViewRow.Cells[columnIndex].Text.StripTags();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Nikita - thanks, but I don't have LinkButtons in the GridView. See the added code in my question above for how I create the links.

Comment: Nikita - this works beautifully, thank you! Just for other reader's reference, I created a public static class called ExtensionMethods in which I put your StripTags function. The class is NOT in a namespace because I have various namespaces in my project. I also found that I needed to pass the parameter as "StripTags(this string html)", adding the keyword "this". Again, THANK YOU!

Comment: I, personally, love how extension methods can be helpful! If you add `ref`, it gets even cooler with less code :) Have fun!

Comment: This solution does not remove links, it removes all text altogether. In addition, some cells are null and this solution does not consider this.